# Is there a way to create a simple equation using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, removing-whitespace

I'm a beginner in java, and I am trying to figure out why 2 operands with an operator "without spaces" is not allowed in a scanner.

I'm trying to do an output that does

```
enter an operand with an operator and another operand: 
1+1 
The answer is: 2.0
```

The first and last lines is ok to understand, but the 2nd line I thought it would be simple, but I get an error when I put 1+1. However when I do 1 + 1 it works (with spaces). I declared 3 variables to input in the scanner:

```
double input1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
char operator = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
double input2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

I tried this but an error occurred, but by doing 1 + 1 using the scanner (above) it worked. Is there a way to remove the spaces between operands and operator?

Comment: `String [] nums = keyboard.nextLine().split("+")` - use Integer.valueOf(nums[0]) etc.

Comment: but the scanner has to be able read any operator not specific and why an array?

Comment: In that case you are better finding a library that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not working because you don't enter it with spaces. Try entering is separately like entering 1 and the enter and then + and the enter and then 1. 
>   hope This helps you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class operations{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the equation");
      String eq  = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println(eq);
      String[] result = eq.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
      System.out.println(result[0]);
      System.out.println(result[1]);
      System.out.println(result[2]);
   }
}
```